# Trying to grep lines of output for a string, then return $3 (column 3) + that found string

Tags: awk, grep

I have many lines of text in a file - EACH line in this format:

```
blah blah filename1 blah blah blah blah text { ANY TEXT ANY HERE } blah blah blah
```

For any lines that have 'text { whatever }' Im trying to get the 3rd column ($3) appended in front of the found text 'text { whatever }'

So I have the last part working, I just need to grab that $3:

```
cat data.txt | grep -oP 'text {/*?}'
```

****UPDATED for more accurate scenario***
Here is the actual lines of code its scanning (Its an F5 load balancer config):

```
ltm virtual www.testapp.com_80 { creation-time 2021-09-11:00:01:39 destination 10.105.34.20:http ip-protocol tcp last-modified-time 2021-09-11:19:56:16 mask 255.255.255.255 profiles { http { } tcp { } } rules { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect } source 0.0.0.0/0 source-address-translation { type automap } translate-address enabled translate-port enabled vs-index 14 }

ltm virtual www.testapp2.com_443 { creation-time 2022-02-17:05:06:52 destination 10.105.34.23:https ip-protocol tcp last-modified-time 2022-02-17:05:06:52 mask 255.255.255.255 profiles { http { } tcp { } } rules { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect } source 0.0.0.0/0 translate-address enabled translate-port enabled vs-index 20 }
```

These are just two lines that are representative of a HUUGE config file.

I just need the $3 (3rd column) from that line (VIP website name which is present in each line) printed with the irules listed  " rules { text in here }"

So for those two lines... I am looking for output that looks like:

```
www.testapp.com_80 { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }
www.testapp2.com_443 { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }
```

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for your posted sample input (but first change that input to use different strings everywhere, not repeat strings such that we can't tell in  the output where they came from).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(^| )rules *{[^}]*}/){ x=$3; $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $1=x; print }' file
www.testapp.com_80 { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }
www.testapp2.com_443 { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }
```

Comment: I reposted the actual lines of code Im pulling from above in the chat and the desired text.  So $3 could be anything.   text { Any TEXT } would literally be any text... not the actual words.  I apologize if I wasnt clear - struggling with telling people "ANY TEXT IN HERE" literally means any text - not the actual words.   LOL I just gave myself a migraine.

Comment: I don't think anyone thought you literally meant the words "ANY TEXT IN HERE" but I also dont think you literally mean **ANY** text. For example, when you say **any text** - if that includes `{` and/or `}` and/or `\n` then this would become a harder problem to solve so hopefully that's not what you mean. I updated my answer but the original would have worked for you if you had just changed `text` to `rules`, you'd just have had to tweak what was output as your original question wasn't clear if the `text` should be output or not, and tweaked it to work for nexted `text { ... }`s.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you could try following code. Written and tested in GNU `sed` with its `-E` option to enable ERE regex, with your shown samples. Using `sed`'s capability of using capturing groups to store matched values into temp buffer memory which could be used later on while performing substitution in `sed`.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/n0aJJ4/1) for used regex in below `sed` code.

```bash
sed -E 's/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+) .*(\{[^}]*}).*/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

Comment: Wow.  Im still trying to wrap my head around how/what this is doing but its 99% working.    It seems to be grabbing whatever is contained in the last set of curly braces (rightmost).  If there are multiple curly braces (and there are as this is JSON) then it grabs the rightmost set.   What Im looking for is to look for a specific set of curly braces.  I will update my post above with exact info.

Comment: So if you noticed in my update in my question you will see the actual source data and I apologize I was trying to simplify it for folks so I didnt confuse anyone with a bunch of JSON but I forgot these are all programmers here. LOL.    Here is the output from my actual data: posted in the edited question:    `www.testapp.com_80 { type automap }`<br/>
`www.testapp2.com_443  { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }`

Comment: apoligies having difficulty inserting <CR> line breaks after each line

Comment: So the desired result would have been `www.testapp.com_80 { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }` <br/> `www.testapp2.com_443  { HTTP_to_HTTPS_Redirect }`

Comment: @JStryker, could you please elaborate more on same, would like to help on same, thank you.